# Jetpack Compose Date Picker Dialog UI

Tags: java, kotlin, datepicker, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I recently implemented a Date Picker dialog. How it works as of now is I have an OutlinedTextField Composable and a transparent button laying over top of it so that the appearance matches my other fields which don't require a date picker. Once the user clicks on the Date Picker TextField a dialog will pop up with a label at the top of the dialog along with 3 ItemPickers which allow the user to select a day, month, and year from a defined range. Once the user has selected the date and clicks the "Done" button, the dialog closes and the globalViewModel's date field gets updated with the selection. The problem that I am having is that when the user reopens the datepicker after the first selection, the date picker does not display the previously selected date and instead defaults to the current date. I have tried to add a conditional statement to check if the viewmodel is populated and if it is then replace the current day with the one saved in the viewmodel but this unfortunately makes my app crash and I have no idea how to fix it otherwise.

[This is what the date picker looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzVim.jpg)

This is my code

````
@Composable
fun DatePickerUI(
    label: String,
    globalViewModel: GlobalSavedViewModel,
    onDismissRequest: () -> Unit
) {
    Card(
        shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
    ) {
        Column(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(vertical = 10.dp, horizontal = 5.dp)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = label,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                style = AdditionalTypography.bodyMedium
            )

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))

            val chosenYear = remember { mutableStateOf(currentYear) }
            val chosenMonth = remember { mutableStateOf(currentMonth) }
            val chosenDay = remember { mutableStateOf(currentDay) }
            DateSelectionSection(
                onYearChosen = { chosenYear.value = it.toInt() },
                onMonthChosen = { chosenMonth.value = monthsNames.indexOf(it) },
                onDayChosen = { chosenDay.value = it.toInt() },
                globalViewModel = globalViewModel,
                dateType = label,
            )

            Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(30.dp))

            Button(
                shape = RoundedCornerShape(5.dp),
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .padding(horizontal = 10.dp),
                onClick = {
                    val date = chosenYear.value.toString().substring(2) + if(chosenMonth.value.toString().length == 1) {"0"} else {""} + (chosenMonth.value + 1).toString() + if(chosenDay.value.toString().length == 1) {"0"} else {""} + chosenDay.value.toString()
                    if(label == "Date of Birth") {
                        globalViewModel.updateDateOfBirth(date)
                    }
                    else {
                        globalViewModel.updateDateOfExpiration(date)
                    }
                    onDismissRequest()
                }
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Done",
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    style = AdditionalTypography.bodyMedium
                )
            }
        }
    }
}

@SuppressLint("StateFlowValueCalledInComposition")
@Composable
fun DateSelectionSection(
    onYearChosen: (String) -> Unit,
    onMonthChosen: (String) -> Unit,
    onDayChosen: (String) -> Unit,
    globalViewModel: GlobalSavedViewModel,
    dateType: String,
) {
    Row(
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceAround,
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(100.dp)
    ) {
        InfiniteItemsPicker(
            items = days,
            firstIndex = Int.MAX_VALUE / 2 + (currentDay - 2),
            onItemSelected = onDayChosen
        )

        InfiniteItemsPicker(
            items = monthsNames,
            firstIndex = Int.MAX_VALUE / 2 - 4 + currentMonth,
            onItemSelected = onMonthChosen
        )

        InfiniteItemsPicker(
            items = years,
            firstIndex = Int.MAX_VALUE / 2 + (currentYear - 1925),
            onItemSelected = onYearChosen
        )
    }
}

@SuppressLint("FrequentlyChangedStateReadInComposition")
@Composable
fun InfiniteItemsPicker(
    items: List<String>,
    firstIndex: Int,
    onItemSelected: (String) -> Unit,
) {

    val listState = rememberLazyListState(firstIndex)
    val currentValue = remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    LaunchedEffect(key1 = !listState.isScrollInProgress) {
        onItemSelected(currentValue.value)
        listState.animateScrollToItem(index = listState.firstVisibleItemIndex)
    }

    Box(modifier = Modifier.height(106.dp)) {
        LazyColumn(
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            state = listState,
            content = {
                items(count = Int.MAX_VALUE, itemContent = {
                    val index = it % items.size
                    if (it == listState.firstVisibleItemIndex + 1) {
                        currentValue.value = items[index]
                    }

                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(6.dp))

                    Text(
                        text = items[index],
                        modifier = Modifier.alpha(if (it == listState.firstVisibleItemIndex + 1) 1f else 0.3f),
                        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                        style = AdditionalTypography.bodyMedium
                    )

                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(6.dp))
                })
            }
        )
    }
}

@Composable
fun formatMRZDate(date: String): String {
    if(date.length == 6) {
        Log.i("DatePicker", date.substring(2,4) + "-" + date.substring(4,6) + "-" + date.substring(0,2))
        return date.substring(2,4) + "-" + date.substring(4,6) + "-" + date.substring(0,2)
    }
    return ""
}

val currentYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)
val currentDay = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
val currentMonth = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH)

val years = (1900..2100).map { it.toString() }
val monthsNumber = (1..12).map { it.toString() }
val days = (1..31).map { it.toString() }
val monthsNames = listOf(
    "JAN",
    "FEB",
    "MAR",
    "APR",
    "MAY",
    "JUN",
    "JUL",
    "AUG",
    "SEP",
    "OCT",
    "NOV",
    "DEC"
)```
````

Comment: Can you share Viewmodel code? The issue you are facing is likely because you're initializing the chosenYear, chosenMonth, and chosenDay states with the current date values (currentYear, currentMonth, currentDay) every time when the DatePickerUI composable is recomposed. To fix this, you need to initialize these states with the values stored in your globalViewModel when available.